# Guzzle conflict between CiviCRM and Community Builder (Joomla)?

Tags: joomla, registration

my Community Builder registration process seems to have started failing since I updated CiviCRM recently.

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare GuzzleHttp\describe_type() (previously declared in [DOCROOT]/libraries/CBLib/GuzzleHttp/functions.php:14) in [DOCROOT]/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions.php on line 41

I guess there are two versions of GuzzleHttp conflicting but I'm not sure how I go about resolving this.  This maybe isn't specifically a CiviCRM problem, but I'd very much appreciate some guidance on how to troubleshoot this!

Joomla 3.10.10
CiviCRM 5.50.2
Community Builder 2.7.3

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These links are for drupal and wordpress but it's the same type of problem. There isn't a good solution available though.

- https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1968
- https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3781

In this specific case, my guess is that community builder is using guzzle 7 (the source code for community builder doesn't seem available online to check???). If that's true, then since civi supports guzzle 7 but just ships with guzzle 6, what you can try is go into the civicrm plugin folder and run `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:'^7'` so that they end up with the same version. If something goes wrong just `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:'^6.3'` to restore the old guzzle for civi.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, I'll check with the developers on Community Builder.

Comment: So the Community Builder developers have confirmed they're using Guzzle 7, so I will need to change the version in Civi.  Please forgive a potentially stupid question, but I have very limited experience with Composer.  This CiviCRM instance was installed via the Joomla installer, and I've never managed it with Composer. Can I set up composer on an already installed Civi? If so, which is the correct plugin folder to use?

Comment: This really is a separate question, so I've made a separate post :-) https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/42429/is-it-possible-to-use-composer-with-a-joomla-installed-civicrm-instance

Comment: Just thought I'd report back -- running the composer require to change the guzzle version is working.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Great. Glad it's working.