# is it possible to use composer with a Joomla-installed CiviCRM instance?

Tags: joomla, composer

I have an extension version conflict problem on my Joomla site, for which the recommended solution is to change the civicrm dependencies via composer ([Guzzle conflict between CiviCRM and Community Builder (Joomla)?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/42419/guzzle-conflict-between-civicrm-and-community-builder-joomla/42420)).

However, this CiviCRM was installed via the Joomla plugin system, and has never been managed by composer.  So essentially, I don't know how to implement the solution :-)

Composer is installed on the server where CiviCRM resides.  Is it possible to set up composer to manage the Civicrm instance after-the-fact, so I can change these dependencies?  I can't find any documentation on how to do this (all the documentation I'm finding re: CiviCRM and composer are for Drupal).

Help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no documentation because it's not really something you would normally do. I admit I don't know how joomla works - in the download file it looks like it might end up in com_civicrm/admin/civicrm? You're looking for a file named `composer.json`. Then using the command line in that same folder, you'd type `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:'^7'`

Comment: Thanks for answering here as well :-) The correct folder is /administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm, and there is indeed a composer.json file in that directory.  I just wanted to confirm that running composer at this point would not screw up the civicrm installation in any unexpected ways.  I guess the best process would be to backup the site and give it a try.

Comment: Backup is always good. The command would only affect that folder and subfolders.